# Area of one petal of a rose

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How would I go about finding the area of one petal of the rose $r=|cos(2\theta)|^{1/2} $
Not sure how i deal with the power to the half. 
I know that without the power to the half, the area would simply be $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{cos(2\theta)}rdrd\theta$, but i am not sure how the power to the half will affect it.

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^{f(\theta)} rdr = \frac12 f(\theta)^2$

Answer (score 1):

$$2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}d\theta\int_0^\sqrt{cos(2\theta)}rdr=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}cos(2\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

The area is given by
$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{2}r^2\,d\theta=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{2}\cos2\theta\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

With the half power, the area integral is set similarly

$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{cos(2\theta)}}rdrd\theta$$